# xpath is there any way to select tr in a regulat basis?

Tags: xpath

I have a page with content and table like this:

```
table
  tr
  tr
  tr
  tr (needed)
  tr
  tr
  tr
  tr
  tr
  tr
  tr
  tr (needed)
  tr
  tr
  tr
  tr
  tr
  tr
  tr
  tr(needed)
...
```

I want to extract the tr in these positions

```
4, 12, 20, 28 .....
```

so in other words, i want to take the `tr` in position `4` and then get the tr `4+8` and then get the tr `4+8+8`.... and so on

is there anyway to get that using xpath?

Comment: XPath has an union operation, eg: `'//table/tr[4]|//table/tr[12]|//table/tr[20]'` but this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: @marbu why not? If there is not other solution, I must try with your solution right? The table contains maximum 30 **needed** `tr`. So, do you suggest making a hard code ?

Comment: well if you have such small limit on the size of input document, it would be ugly, but it should work fine.

Comment: @marbu could you give me an reference to that feature please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you can do this quite concisely and efficiently, and without any fixed limit on the possible number of `tr`s:

```
//table/tr[(position() mod 8) = 4]
```

This will select `tr` number 4, 12, 20, ... 8n + 4, etc.